# ¿Cómo hacer media de valores de cada mes en R?

Tags: r

Estoy tratando datos climáticos de precipitación en R y tengo una serie de datos donde hay un valor de lluvia por cada día desde 1964.

En algunas ocasiones existen datos faltantes que los transformo en NA al importar el excel.
Hay una columna (día) con el día del año, otra (mes) con el numero del mes, otra (año, o ano) con el numero de año.

Necesito generar la media de cada mes para todos los años. Por ejemplo la media de precipitación de todos los Julios o de todos los Eneros...

Estoy usando este código, pero no parece ser el adecuado:

```
if(pira_cacchan_recu_99_9_p_1_2_1964$mes == 1){is.na(media_pira <- mean(pira_cacchan_recu_99_9_p_1_2_1964$ppira),
                                                     media_cacchan <- mean(pira_cacchan_recu_99_9_p_1_2_1964$pcacchan),
                                                     media_recuay <- mean(pira_cacchan_recu_99_9_p_1_2_1964$precuay)}

print(media_pira)
print(media_cacchan)
print(media_recuay)
```

Alguna idea sobre qué puedo hacer? o como llevar la media a cabo?

Para poneros en situación:

- pira_cacchan_recu_99_9_p_1_2_1964   es el excel
- ppira, cacchan y recuay, son columnas en el excel que corresponden con cada estación meteoroógica.
- la columna pira_cacchan_recu_99_9_p_1_2_1964$mes se corresponde con el numero del mes a tratar. Como si fuese un código o identificador.

Answer (score 0):

Primero armamos un ejemplo similar a lo que mencionas:

```
set.seed(2019)
pira_cacchan_recu_99_9_p_1_2_1964 <- data.frame(
    anio=sample(2010:2019, 1000, replace = TRUE),
    mes=sample(1:12, 1000, replace = TRUE),
    pira=runif(1000),
    cacchan=runif(1000),
    recuay_pira=runif(1000)
)
```

La forma más sencilla de resolverlo es agrupar por `mes` y aplicar la media sobre cada grupo. Con R base puedes hacer:

```
aggregate(. ~ mes, pira_cacchan_recu_99_9_p_1_2_1964[, -1], mean)
```

En este caso, la formula `. ~ mes` indica, agrupar por mes y aplicar la función al resto de las columnas, por lo que deberemos quitar el `anio` del `data.frame` con `pira_cacchan_recu_99_9_p_1_2_1964[, -1]`.

O también de forma más explícita, indicando las columnas

```
aggregate(cbind(pira, cacchan, recuay_pira) ~ mes, 
          pira_cacchan_recu_99_9_p_1_2_1964, 
          mean)
```

El resultado es un `data.frame` similar a este:

```
   mes      pira   cacchan recuay_pira
1    1 0.4795477 0.4708852   0.5381664
2    2 0.5406359 0.5481458   0.4475143
3    3 0.4738244 0.5104678   0.5427169
4    4 0.5307465 0.4873170   0.4380420
5    5 0.5721667 0.5065329   0.4993786
6    6 0.4738371 0.4624162   0.4913951
7    7 0.4723656 0.5191485   0.5146974
8    8 0.5189350 0.4937346   0.5425428
9    9 0.5426415 0.4646704   0.4727523
10  10 0.5245901 0.5264539   0.4962397
11  11 0.5276531 0.5324419   0.4848972
12  12 0.4979666 0.4551696   0.4947938
```

Si eventualmente usas o piensas usar `dplyr`, puedes hacer lo siguiente, que tiene la ventaja de ser mucho más explicativo:

```
library(tidyverse)

pira_cacchan_recu_99_9_p_1_2_1964 %>% 
    group_by(mes) %>% 
    summarise_at(vars(pira, cacchan, recuay_pira), mean, na.rm=TRUE)
```

nota: `aggregate()` por defecto omite los valores `NA`, en el caso de `dplyr/summarize_at()`, no, por lo que hay que indicar `na.rm=TRUE` como parámetro adicional a `mean()`.